# An image on my site is showing as the wrong image

Tags: images, css

I have an image on my site, which is showing up as the wrong image. When I "inspect element" in chrome, and click on the link to the image, it shows up as the right image.

How can this be?

Here's the page: http://goinspire.com/israel-family-tours/

The image is the blue triangle that appears when you scroll down.

The image: http://goinspire.com/wp-content/uploads/arrow2.gif

Thanks!!

Comment: What should the image be?

Comment: Thanks! It's this: http://goinspire.com/wp-content/uploads/arrow2.gif

Comment: this is because you are mentioned the height and width 122 *105 then it should work

Comment: When I uncheck those 2 CSS elements, the picture disappears. Was that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only seeing the top of the image, because your background image is much larger than the size you have for #smoothup in the css:

in style.css `#smoothup {height: 40px; width: 90px;}`

The actual image is 122 x 105.

You need either:

1: modify the css defining #smoothup to fit the size of the background image

or

2 modify the background image to fit the size of the container

or

3: use CSS3 `background-size` to scale the background image (not supported in IE8 and below) and would look wrong because you are not matching the aspect ratio.

If you are deliberately scaling the image down for retina display, you put it in the code as an `img` element and scale down with css, but **maintain the aspect ratio**

Comment: Cool!!!! I didn't even think that maybe it was a scaling problem. Thanks!